# How to create Prestashop product with custom attributes programatically?

Tags: module, prestashop-1.5

Maybe some of you who uses prestashop core classes know how to create product with custom attributes? I mean add new product in prestashop system by creating script that uses prestashop class for this purpose programatically.

Answer (score 2):

[@Santo Boldižar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8750652/santo-boldi%C5%BEar)

His code working fine.if you create new attribute programmatically use below code to add a new attribute and get **$idProductAttribute**

```
   use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Import\ImportDataFormatter;

    $newGroup = new AttributeGroup();
    $newGroup->name = ImportDataFormatter::createMultiLangField('test');
    $newGroup->public_name = ImportDataFormatter::createMultiLangField('test');
    $newGroup->group_type = 'select';
    $newGroup->add();

    $newAttribute = new Attribute();
    $newAttribute->name = ImportDataFormatter::createMultiLangField('test');
    $newAttribute->id_attribute_group = $newGroup->id;
    $newAttribute->add();

     $idProductAttribute = $product->addProductAttribute($price,
        $weight,
        $unit_impact,
        $ecotax,
        $quantity,
        $id_images,
        $reference,
        $id_supplier,
        $ean13,
        $default,
        $location,
        $upc,
        $minimal_quantity,
        $isbn,
        $low_stock_threshold,
        $low_stock_alert);

    $product->addAttributeCombinaison($idProductAttribute, array($newAttribute->id_attribute_group));
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I created products with attributes in **PrestaShop 1.7.5**, here a part of my code.

First load the product:

```
$product = new \Product($productId);
```

Then, add an attribute to this product:

```
// The $data array contains all of the required data for an attribute.

$idProductAttribute = $product->addProductAttribute(
    (float)$data['price'],          // Product price (+/-) - If the base product price is 50 and you set here -5, the new price will be 45
    (float)$data['weight'],         // Product weight
    $data['unit_impact'],
    $data['ecotax'],
    (int)$data['quantity'],         // Products available in stock
    $data['id_images'],             // Image ids
    $data['reference'],
    strval($data['suppliers']),
    strval($data['ean13']),         // Barcode
    $data['default'],               // Default product or not (1/0)
    $data['location'],
    $data['upc'],
    $data['minimal_quantity'],      // Default 1
    $data['isbn']
);

$product->addAttributeCombinaison($idProductAttribute, $data['attribute_ids']); // $data['attribute_ids'] - id(s) of existing attribute(s).
```

And voilá, you have a product with a new attribute.